# Getting altitude with Trimble TDC 100 and QField

Tags: qfield, trimble, altitude, data-collection, z-value

In our company we got Trimble TDC 100 and install QFlied for data collection. We collect points and polylines. Our aim is to get vertex and points while saving their altitude (height above the mean sea level).

When we work on the desktop project, we enable the "Z". But after the field collection, Z($geometry) just products "0" not the altitude. How to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to add more details on how you're configuring the data storage. Are you using shapefiles, geopackage...

Comment: Hi thanks for answering ... i used shapefiles organised through a qgis project ... Qfield just opens it ... When i create the shapefile, i enable the z extraction but it doesn't work ...